# Macro doesn't start with a button

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue while i execute a macro.

When i execute it Line by line it works perfectly (Slow, but perfect).
But when i execute it with a Button in the graphic inteface, it doesn't even open the Excel File that is necessary to run the procedure.

Below i will link my code, because i don't even know what is happening.

I'm thinking that it must be some issue related with the weight of the procedure. But i don't know really.

Thank you by the way.

```
Sub Estructura_Activo_Fijo()

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wbEstructura As Workbook
Dim wsTAG As Worksheet

Dim xWBName As String
Dim xWb As Workbook

    Dim est
    Dim consfinal
    Dim boc
    Dim bct
    Dim consoc

    On Error Resume Next
    xWBName = "Estructura.xlsx"
    Set wbEstructura = Application.Workbooks(xWBName)

    If wbEstructura Is Nothing Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Estructura.xlsx"
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    xWBName = "Consolidado Final.xlsx"
    Set xWb = Application.Workbooks(xWBName)

    If xWb Is Nothing Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\BBDD\Biblioteca\BBDD Locales\Consolidado Final.xlsx"
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    xWBName = "BBDD OC.xlsx"
    Set xWb = Application.Workbooks(xWBName)

    On Error Resume Next
    If xWb Is Nothing Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\BBDD OC.xlsx"
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    xWBName = "BBDD CT.xlsx"
    Set xWb = Application.Workbooks(xWBName)

    If xWb Is Nothing Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\BBDD CT.xlsx"
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    xWBName = "Consolidado OC.xlsx"
    Set xWb = Application.Workbooks(xWBName)

    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Consolidado OC.xlsx"
    End If

ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized

Set wbEstructura = Workbooks("Estructura.xlsx")
Set wsTAG = wbEstructura.Worksheets("TAG")
Workbooks("Estructura.xlsx").Activate

Dim rng1 As Range, FSO
Dim rngTipo As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim error As Long
Dim existente As Long


Dim inicioTiempo As Double
Dim minutosTranscurridos As String



    Set rng1 = wsTAG.Range("B2")
    Set rngTipo = wsTAG.Range("AE2")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ruta = ActiveWorkbook.Path



inicioTiempo = Timer


    rutaAño = ruta & "\2017"

    rutaFARFI = rutaAño & "\FAR_FI"
    rutaFARTA = rutaAño & "\FAR_TA"
    rutaFARTN = rutaAño & "\FAR_TN"
    rutaGOPMTI = rutaAño & "\GOPM_TI"


    If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaAño) Then
            MkDir ruta & "\2017"
            i = i + 1
        Else
            existente = existente + 1
            MsgBox "La carpeta \2017 ya existe, el proceso se cerrará.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
    End If





    If Len(Dir(rutaFARFI, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir rutaFARFI
    Else
        existente = existente + 1
    End If

    If Len(Dir(rutaFARTA, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir rutaFARTA
    Else
        existente = existente + 1
    End If

    If Len(Dir(rutaFARTN, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir rutaFARTN
    Else
        existente = existente + 1
    End If

    If Len(Dir(rutaGOPMTI, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir rutaGOPMTI
    Else
        existente = existente + 1
    End If



    Do While Not IsEmpty(rng1)



    If FSO.FolderExists(rutaAño) Then


        v = rng1.Offset(0, 29).Value



        Do While IsEmpty(rngTipo)

            error = error + 1
            Set rngTipo = rngTipo.Offset(1, 0)

        Loop


        If v = "Padre" Then 'Si 'v' es Padre:



        If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaFARFI & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value2) Then

            FSO.CreateFolder (rutaFARFI & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value2)
            i = i + 1
            padre = padre + 1

        Else
            existente = existente + 1
        End If


        If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaFARTA & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value2) Then

            FSO.CreateFolder (rutaFARTA & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value2)
            i = i + 1
            padre = padre + 1

        Else
            existente = existente + 1
        End If


        If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaFARTN & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value2) Then
            FSO.CreateFolder (rutaFARTN & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value2)
            i = i + 1
            padre = padre + 1
        Else
            existente = existente + 1
        End If


        If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaGOPMTI & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value2) Then
            FSO.CreateFolder (rutaGOPMTI & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value2)
            i = i + 1
            padre = padre + 1
        Else
        existente = existente + 1
        End If


            rutaPadreFARFI = rutaFARFI & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value
            rutaPadreFARTA = rutaFARTA & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value
            rutaPadreFARTN = rutaFARTN & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value
            rutaPadreGOPMTI = rutaGOPMTI & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value

                              ElseIf v = "Componente" Then





                              If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARFI & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value) Then
                              FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARFI & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value)
                              i = i + 1
                              componente = componente + 1
                              Else
                              existente = existente + 1
                              End If

                              If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARTA & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value) Then
                              FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARTA & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value)
                              i = i + 1
                              componente = componente + 1
                              Else
                              existente = existente + 1
                              End If

                              If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARTN & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value) Then
                              FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARTN & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value)
                              i = i + 1
                              componente = componente + 1
                              Else
                              existente = existente + 1
                              End If

                              If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreGOPMTI & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value) Then
                              FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreGOPMTI & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value)
                              i = i + 1
                              componente = componente + 1
                              Else
                              existente = existente + 1
                              End If

                    rutaCompFARFI = rutaPadreFARFI & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value
                    rutaCompFARTA = rutaPadreFARTA & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value
                    rutaCompFARTN = rutaPadreFARTN & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value
                    rutaCompGOPMTI = rutaPadreGOPMTI & "\" & Left(v, 1) & rng1.Value

    End If


            w = rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value


             If v = "Padre" Then


               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARFI & "\" & w) Then
                FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARFI & "\" & w)
                j = j + 1
               Else
                existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARFI & "\OC") Then
                FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARFI & "\OC")
                j = j + 1
               Else
                existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARFI & "\EP") Then
                FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARFI & "\EP")
                j = j + 1
               Else
                existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARFI & "\CAP") Then
                FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARFI & "\CAP")
                j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If





               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARTA & "\" & w) Then
                FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARTA & "\" & w)
                j = j + 1
               Else
                existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARTA & "\OC") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARTA & "\OC")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARTA & "\EP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARTA & "\EP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARTA & "\CAP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARTA & "\CAP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If





               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARTN & "\" & w) Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARTN & "\" & w)
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARTN & "\OC") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARTN & "\OC")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARTN & "\EP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARTN & "\EP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreFARTN & "\CAP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreFARTN & "\CAP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If





               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreGOPMTI & "\" & w) Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreGOPMTI & "\" & w)
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreGOPMTI & "\OC") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreGOPMTI & "\OC")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If
               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreGOPMTI & "\EP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreGOPMTI & "\EP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaPadreGOPMTI & "\CAP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaPadreGOPMTI & "\CAP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If



               ElseIf v = "Componente" Then




               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompFARFI & "\" & w) Then
                FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompFARFI & "\" & w)
                j = j + 1
               Else
                existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompFARFI & "\OC") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompFARFI & "\OC")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompFARFI & "\EP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompFARFI & "\EP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompFARFI & "\CAP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompFARFI & "\CAP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If



               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompFARTA & "\" & w) Then
                FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompFARTA & "\" & w)
                j = j + 1
               Else
                existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompFARTA & "\OC") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompFARTA & "\OC")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompFARTA & "\EP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompFARTA & "\EP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompFARTA & "\CAP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompFARTA & "\CAP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If



               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompFARTN & "\" & w) Then
                FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompFARTN & "\" & w)
                j = j + 1
               Else
                existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompFARTN & "\OC") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompFARTN & "\OC")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompFARTN & "\EP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompFARTN & "\EP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompFARTN & "\CAP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompFARTN & "\CAP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If



               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompGOPMTI & "\" & w) Then
                FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompGOPMTI & "\" & w)
                j = j + 1
               Else
                existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompGOPMTI & "\OC") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompGOPMTI & "\OC")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompGOPMTI & "\EP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompGOPMTI & "\EP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If

               If Not FSO.FolderExists(rutaCompGOPMTI & "\CAP") Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (rutaCompGOPMTI & "\CAP")
               j = j + 1
               Else
               existente = existente + 1
               End If




             End If



        '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
        '---Creación y Asignacion de carpeta para el archivo Excel Padre.---'
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------'



        Dim fi, tb As String
        Dim TabName As String

        TabName = rng1.Value

        rutaFichas = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\BBDD\Fichas SGM"

        If v = "Padre" Then




            If rutaPadreFARFI = rutaFARFI & "\" & "P" & TabName Then


                fi = "FAR - FIN.xlsm"
                Workbooks.Open Filename:=rutaFichas & "\" & fi
                Range("D5").Value = TabName
                ActiveSheet.Name = TabName

                With ThisWorkbook
                    .Worksheets(TabName).Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                    .Worksheets(TabName).Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                End With

                With ThisWorkbook
                    .Worksheets("Distribucion").Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                    .Worksheets("Distribucion").Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=rutaPadreFARFI & "\" & TabName
                ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
                k = k + 1


            End If


            If rutaPadreFARTA = rutaFARTA & "\" & "P" & TabName Then


                tb = "FAR - TRIB.xlsm"
                Workbooks.Open Filename:=rutaFichas & "\" & tb
                Range("D5").Value = TabName
                ActiveSheet.Name = TabName


                With ThisWorkbook
                    .Worksheets(TabName).Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                    .Worksheets(TabName).Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                End With

                With ThisWorkbook
                    .Worksheets("Distribucion").Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                    .Worksheets("Distribucion").Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=rutaPadreFARTA & "\" & TabName
                ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
                k = k + 1


            End If

            If rutaPadreFARTN = rutaFARTN & "\" & "P" & TabName Then

                tb = "FAR - TRIB.xlsm"
                Workbooks.Open Filename:=rutaFichas & "\" & tb
                Range("D5").Value = TabName
                ActiveSheet.Name = TabName

                With ThisWorkbook
                    .Worksheets(TabName).Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                    .Worksheets(TabName).Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                End With

                With ThisWorkbook
                    .Worksheets("Distribucion").Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                    .Worksheets("Distribucion").Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=rutaPadreFARTN & "\" & TabName
                ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
                k = k + 1

            End If


            If rutaPadreGOPMTI = rutaGOPMTI & "\" & "P" & TabName Then



                tb = "FAR - TRIB.xlsm"
                Workbooks.Open Filename:=rutaFichas & "\" & tb
                Range("D5").Value = TabName
                ActiveSheet.Name = TabName

                With ThisWorkbook
                    .Worksheets(TabName).Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                    .Worksheets(TabName).Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                End With

                With ThisWorkbook
                    .Worksheets("Distribucion").Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                    .Worksheets("Distribucion").Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=rutaPadreGOPMTI & "\" & TabName
                ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
                k = k + 1

            End If


        End If


    Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0)
    Set rngTipo = rngTipo.Offset(1, 0)

    End If

    Loop

    Workbooks("Consolidado Final.xlsx").Close
    Workbooks("Consolidado OC.xlsx").Close
    Workbooks("BBDD CT.xlsx").Close
    Workbooks("BBDD OC.xlsx").Close

    minutosTranscurridos = Format((Timer - inicioTiempo) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")


Set FSO = Nothing

'Se reactiva la propiedad de actualización.}
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized 'Se maximiza la ventana para mostrar el menu
End Sub
```

Comment: But does at least start the macro?

Comment: There's too much code here.  Without any more details  - does it error and on what line? - it's difficult to make any suggestions.  Other than comment out *all* of your `On Error Resume Next` lines.

Comment: You deserve a medal for persistence! But the result is not a macro, it is a cancer. If the word "macro" invites you to think big, please write a "micro". Create one `Main` procedure which calls `Sub`s or `Function`s that process your data.

Comment: Remove all `On Error Resume Next` statements. Not only the only one that actually does anything is the first one, each one of them is telling VBA: "whatever error you encounter - file not found, bad format, corrupt workbook, whatever - I don't want to know. Just keep running in whatever unknown error state, let me know when you're done" - in other words, there's an error somewhere, but OERN is deliberately ignoring it.

Comment: On my PC your code fails to compile starting at `rutaA?o = ruta & "\2017"`. This might be due to your use of an indigenous character which might be at the core of your problem. Don't use it.

Comment: Tip: `Workbooks.Open` is a function, it returns a `Workbook` object reference... it returns the very same workbook object you're fetching 3 instructions later by dereferencing it from the `Application.Workbooks` collection, using its hard-coded filename.

Comment: `On error resume next` (OERN) is active until the code sees a change in the way it should handle errors like `On error goto 0`.  All OERN following the first one are of no use.  Also, code should almost always be tested without any OERN.  In your final version, OERN should be used only when it's the only possible way to distinguish two different states in the code and where you are 100% sure there will be no other error than the one you predicted.  Lastly, OERN should almost immediately be followed by a `On error goto 0`  so you use your OERN at a precise moment in the code and then its off.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you might split your code into useful VBA components. Define "useful" as something that does more work for you than it eats up of your time.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Estructura_Activo_Fijo()

    Dim WbEstructura As Workbook
    Dim WbX As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not GetWorkbook("Estructura.xlsx", WbEstructura) Then GoTo SideExit
    If Not GetWorkbook("BBDD\Biblioteca\BBDD Locales\Consolidado Final.xlsx", WbX) Then GoTo SideExit

SideExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function GetWorkbook(ByVal FilePath As String, _
                             Wb As Workbook) As Boolean

    Dim Sp() As String                  ' split FilePath
    Dim Ffn As String                   ' Full File Name
    Dim Fn As String                    ' File name

    Sp = Split(FilePath, "\")
    Fn = Sp(UBound(Sp))

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Wb = Application.Workbooks(Fn)
    If Err.Number = 9 Then              ' 9 = Suscript out of range
        Ffn = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & FilePath
        If Len(Dir(Ffn)) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "I couldn't find the file" & vbCr & _
                   FilePath & vbCr & _
                   "This task must now be abandoned.", _
                   vbCritical, "Unable to open workbook"
        Else
            Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Ffn)
        End If
    End If
    GetWorkbook = Not (Wb Is Nothing)
End Function
```

In this example, I created one function which opens a workbook. You can call it repeatedly for the many workbooks you need to open. All the work is done in the function. In the main procedure opening two workbooks just takes 2 lines of code.

You will notice that the function can do a much better job by itself than if it were part of the main. It can tell you what went wrong. Moreover, it returns TRUE if the workbook was successfully opened, and your main procedure can take action depending upon that event much easier and more transparently.